# Ошибка: Имя не разрешено в данном контексте

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Пишу просто курсор - для практики. Получаем запросом Ид книги и курсором обходим выборку,  выводим ИД пользователю.

```
Declare @BookID int
declare MyCursor2 CURSOR  FOR select BookID from Book;

open MyCursor2

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor2 INTO @BookID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT BookID
END

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor2 INTO @BookID
END

CLOSE MyCursor2
```

Вроде бы по msdn все делаю, да видно что-то не так. Пишет субд ошибки : "Имя "BookID" не разрешено в данном контексте" и

"Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "CLOSE""

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?**
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. уберите точку с запятой после declare cursor
2. print @BookID
3. лишний end после print